# TeXstudio \makeglossaries does not work

Tags: xetex, glossaries

I am using TeXstudio and try to make a glossary.

My code is essentially:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}

\usepackage[acronym, xindy]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{BLA}{BLA}{BLA BLA BLA}

\begin{document}

\gls{BLA}
\clearpage
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

I get no errors, but `\makeglossaries` does not work. It doesn't create or update the glossary.

It only works if I use the command in TeXstudio (Tools -> Glossary). If I compile it it says:

```
Process started: xelatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "main".tex

Process ended normally
```

Do I have to configure TeXstudio differently?

Comment: You may need to manually run `xindy` by clicking TeXstudio's menu item "Tools -> Commands -> Makeglossaries". Then rerun xelatex.

Comment: Yes, I have to manually run the makeglossaries command in the tools menu, but cant latex do that automatically with the \makeglossaries command?

Comment: It seems that TeXstudio does not auto run `makeglossaries` like `bibtex`. [Here](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/buildglossaries/#texstudio) is a workaround to make TeXstudio always run glossaries program when compiling. Alternatively, you can open an issue under [texstudio's github repo](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues) to ask for a new feature.

Comment: I just tested texstudio on my linux box. It handled `makeglossaries` just fine after I hit F9 (Tools -> Glossary). Unlike bibtex you seem to need to run F9 manually, So a normal compilation plus F9 and another compilation and it seems to work